# Can I use one Azure Search Indexer to index multiple entities with the same Key?

Tags: sql, azure, azure-cognitive-search, multiple-entries

Basically I got two datasources(cosmos db, azure sql), one index and two 
indexers.

Both indexers are sharing the same primary key which allows me to join the data from both sources into one index. The issue right now is that the cosmos db contains multiple entries with the same key that is used in the indexers as the primary key, which then by default(I assume) just flattens all entries with the same key and only indexes the latest one found. It runs without errors, but obviously entries are missing as only the last one found is indexed.

The only solution so far is that I index the cosmos db in another indexer using the unique key. I kinda wanted to avoid having multiple search queries, but seems this is the only solution, unless anyone's got a better idea. Thank you!

Comment: By "multiple entries", do you mean there are multiple Cosmos DB documents with the same key, or a single Cosmos DB document with an array of values?

Comment: Multiple documents with the same key which I use as the primary key in the index. Thanks! :)

Comment: Is the key representative of the "identity" of each document, or is it just something you want to search on? How are you currently querying the index?

Comment: Representative of the identity. Right now I'm just playing around with the search explorer in azure and testing which plan will be enough.

Comment: What's the use case of multiple versions of the "same" document? Is it something like historical data?

Comment: Yap. Pretty much, historical data of users. Hence the same Id. I went with having an indexer just for the historical data db.

Comment: Does using username-timestamp as the key work for the user data "snapshots"? You can have other index fields for the username and timestamp, so you can filter by those as well.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not use a same key for multiple docs , key is an unique ID of each doc for looking up. If you adding multiple doc with same key to your index , sys will act multiple update operations on the doc with that key so that you can see the last record only.

Maybe my case is similar as yours which will be helpful , this is my index : 
[image]

And this is the data in my cosmos db : 
[image]

as you can see, the itemid is the key of my index and its value in my cosmos db all are same which is 1 . 
In my case , I use the `_rid` value to replace the `itemid` value while creating data source by sql query below :

```
SELECT u._rid as itemid, u.FirstName , u.LastName,u.Email , u._ts FROM user u  where u._ts >= @HighWaterMark ORDER BY u._ts
```

[image]

As you can see, index has been imported and this issue is solved : 
[image]

With this way , you can import data to your original index without same key issue. 
If there is any misunderstanding or unclear , pls feel free to let me know .

Comment: Problem with that is that I then would lose the actual itemid value as I need it for filtering. Another problem is that I wouldn't be able to use itemid as primary key in another indexer, as that itemid value wouldn't match with the itemid value from the other table.

Comment: It is just for providing a train of thought to solve this issue using cosmos DB datasource query to import docs to your index :)